From matrix to element-wise multiplication in linear recurrences
Suppose I have the linear recurrence $$x_{k+1} =Ax_k+u_k $$
where $x_k \in \mathbb{R}^n, A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, u_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$
Is there a way to re-write this as a recurrence involving element-wise multiplication (Hadamard product) between properly chosen matrices $B, Y$ and $H$? I mean, I would like to have something similar to
$$Y_{k+1} =B*Y_k+H_k $$
from which I can recover my vectors $x_k$.
